# Create and update inside map function

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to find the right way to create and consequently update inside a map function.
These are the steps I need:

1. Map function "reads" the array of elements ids
2. Create new record on "leads_status" table
3. Using the new record id (from "leads_status") "leads" table is updated using "leads_status.id" as foreign key related to "leads.id_ls"

This is the code I tried.

```
const [create, { isLoading: isLoadingCreate, error: errorCreate }] = useCreate();
const [record, setRecord] = React.useState(null);

leadsIDS.map((value, index) => {
    create('leads_status', {
        data: {
            id_lead: value,
            id_status: 5
        }
    }, {
        onSuccess: ({ id }) => {
            setRecord([id, value]);
        },
        onError: () => {
            console.log();
        }
    });
    update('leads', {
        id: record[1],
        data: {
            id_ls: record[0]
        }
    }, {
        enabled: !isLoadingCreate && record !== null
    }, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            console.log(record);
        },
        onError: error => notify('Error', { type: 'warning' })
    })
})
```

I tried also to put the "update" function inside the "create --> onSuccess" but also there the code is not working as I want.
In "leads_status" table records are always created for each element in "leadsIDS" array but in "leads" table only 1 records is updating.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: try with  ```leadsIDS.forEach( async (value) => { await create( ```

Comment: no changes with the addition of async-await and forEach instead of map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useCreate` and `useUpdate` hooks are designed for single actions. If you want to chain several actions, I suggest you use the `useDataProvider` hook, instead, which lets you manipulate Promises.

```
const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
const notify = useNotify();

try {
    await Promise.all(leadsIDS.map(async (value, index) => {
        const { data: leadStatus } = await dataProvider.create('leads_status', {
            data: {
                id_lead: value,
                id_status: 5
            }
        });
        await dataProvider.update('leads', {
            id: value,
            data: { id_ls: leadStatus.id }
        });
    }));    
} catch (e) {
    notify('Error', { type: 'warning' });
}
```